# How do i solve the error : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

Im creating a basic Todo app to improve my skills and etc.
and i hit this error that i cant solve:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
The error is in the text line everytime i remove the as dynamic i hit a bigger error
So that is my code:

```
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
            var item = snapshot.data!.docs[i].data();
            return ListTile(
              title: Text((item as dynamic)['titulo']),
            );
          });
```

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: It sounds like you have a variable that is `Null` and you're trying to treat it like a `String`. A few print statements should illuminate it for you. Also it would help if you simplify your question by providing a minimally reproducible example where you reproduce the problem in the most simple context you can. In doing so, I often answer my own question in the process of preparing a detailed question for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "!" with "?"

```
 return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
      //If it shows error, the add " ?? '' " after snapshot.data?.docs[i].data() 
        var item = snapshot.data?.docs[i].data();
        return ListTile(
          title: Text((item as dynamic)['titulo']),
        );
      });
```